# How to merge different plot but same y axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm always see this kind of graph in XRD plot:
[image]

and i'm wondering how they do that?, if you have different XRD plot and assuming having the same y axis, can matlab do this? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.You can customize it as you want, but this should hopefully get you going.

First create an axes and change its position/size inside the figure, shifting it upward to make room for the 2nd axes as well as removing the x and y labels that you don't want. Then create a 2nd axes with specified position/size to make it fit below the 1st one.

Sample code:

```
clear
clc

%// Generate dummy data
x = 1:2:100;
y1 = rand(1,numel(x));

figure;

%// Make an axes and set its position
haxes1 = axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 .7],'Color',[1 1 1])

%// Plot 1st curve
plot(x,y1,'Parent',haxes1)

%// Remove box and labels
box off
set(gca,'XTickLabel','','XTick',[],'YTick',[])

hold on

%// Get current axes position. You set it so you could get the parameters
%// directly as well.
axes1Pos = get(gca,'Position');

%// Shift 1st axes upward
set(gca,'Position',[axes1Pos(1) 2.6*axes1Pos(2) axes1Pos(3) axes1Pos(4)])

%// Change the poisition/size of the 2nd axes to fit below the 1st one
haxes2 = axes('Position',[axes1Pos(1) axes1Pos(2)/2.5 axes1Pos(3) axes1Pos(4)/2.5]) ;

%// Use linspace to generate colored points to use with scatter.
c = linspace(1,10,length(x));

%// Add 2nd plot and keep only x label
scatter(x,rand(1,numel(x)),40,c,'filled')
set(gca,'YTick',[])

box off

%// Place a ylabel for both axes
text(-4, 1.7,'Super nice y label','rotation',90,'FontSize',16,'HorizontalAlignment','center')
```

Sample output:

[image]

There are other ways to do this as well.

Hope that helps!